# Custom url scheme for deep link from Gmail

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to setup a custom scheme for deep-links like so: `custom://scheme` and have my Android app launch. I could test this scheme from command-line and have my app launch but sending from gmail, doesn't launch my app.

Is setting up a redirect where, `custom://scheme` redirects to `https://www.mywebsite.com/custom/scheme` and since my app can handle `https` scheme launches the app, my only option?

I'd like to know if there are better options.

Comment: Can you provide the html for the email? or is it plain text?. Also provide your intent filter configuration

Comment: I don't have the HTML config but I'd think it uses `href`

Comment: awright, how about your manifest configuration

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is register something similar to what the Play store does:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="market.android.com"
            android:path="/search" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Which captures http urls to a specific host. Otherwise you need the redirect, as yes: Gmail won't directly callout custom schemes.

EDIT: fixed the layout, was not showing the intent filter. If you add a similar intent filter with your own host then if your app is installed it will get first crack at processing the URL (or you'll get a prompt that lets the user choose your app instead of the browser).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you meant by "Which captures http urls to a specific host" ? I mean if I had specified a scheme like so:  `<data android:scheme="custom"
              android:host="scheme" />` where would I register this scheme `custom://scheme` to map to`https://www.mywebsite.com/custom/scheme` ?